# volley not getting the string?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I have a php with red text on it only.
I made a volley request but it is not getting my red word.
what is wrong?

```
private void getColor() {
        final String url = "http://190.128.0.1/color.php";
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                String color = response; //it is not red
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //Log.d("Error.Response", response);
                    }
                }
        );
}
```

Comment: Is there an exception? If so, show us the LogCat output.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add the request to the request queue. Uncomment the logging in your Response listener